# Split file during importation with wget

Tags: split, grep, wget

Hi all I have this code:
`wget --spider -r -v -l1 "$URL" 2>&1 |tee tmp.txt| grep "^--.*Apple" | awk '{ print $3 }' | grep -Eiv '.(txt|css|js|jpg|png|gif)$' | sort -u | split -l 10 -d - file_rid-`

But it split the file when the process is terminated.

How I can have the splitted file during read process?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That should split as the input streams to `split` but that's going to be fairly well buffered by that point because of all the pipes and other processes. Does the `--line-buffered` option to `grep` help at all? (You could replace the `grep | awk | grep` set of steps with *just* `awk` too and that would almost certainly help as well.

Comment: With a `sort` you will get no output beyond that point until all the input has been read, so it's impossible.